# Tensorflow: getting gradients to propagate fully

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to optimize a vector function with Adam in Tensorflow.

```
def getTimeDecayConstant(vec, weights):                                                              
    return (
         tf.math.multiply((1-vec[:, 7]),tf.math.multiply(vec[:, 0],(weights[5] + tf.tensordot(vec[:, 2:7], (weights[0:5]),1)))) + vec[:, 7] * weights[13]
    )                                                                                            
                                                                                                     
def getReviewDecayConstant(vec, weights):                                                            
    return (                                                                                         
            (1-vec[:, 7])*vec[:, 1]*(weights[11] + tf.tensordot(vec[:, 2:7], weights[6:11],1)) + vec[:, 7] * weights[14]
        )                                                                                            
                                                                                                     
def p_recall_vectorized(cards, weights):     
    time_decay_consts   = getTimeDecayConstant(cards, weights)                                       
    review_decay_consts = getReviewDecayConstant(cards, weights)                                     
    return (1-cards[:,7]) * np.exp2(-cards[:,5]/time_decay_consts - cards[:,6]/review_decay_consts) + cards[:,7] * tf.math.sigmoid(weights[12]) 

loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
data = get_array(history)                                                        
labels = np.asarray([x['correct'] for x in history                                    
        ], dtype='float')                                                                        
def optimization_objective(weights = weights_trainable, update=True):
    p_correct = p_recall_vectorized(data, weights_trainable)
    return loss(labels, p_correct)
```

I noticed that only `weights[12]` was changing during the optimization, so I did

```
    with tf.GradientTape() as gfg:                                                               
        gfg.watch(weights_trainable)                                                             
        y = optimization_objective()                                                             
    res = gfg.jacobian(y, weights_trainable)                                                     
    print('res:', res)
```

and found

```
res: tf.Tensor(
[ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
 -0.00474429  0.          0.        ], shape=(15,), dtype=float32)
```

I then verified that `cards[:, 7]` does not equal 1 everywhere and that changing the values of `weights_trainable` gives different return values for `objective_function()`. I also added the calls to `tf.multiply()` in `getTimeDecayConstant` and observed no difference between it and the version with `*` in the same places. So I concluded that `tensorflow` is not registering the gradient of `p_recall_vectorized` in the way I think it would. Can you suggest how to reformulate my functions so that the optimization works?

**Update:** I changed the `np.exp2` to `tf.exp` and the gradients are now defined for everything except `weights_trainable[13]` and `weights_trainable[14]`. Any ideas about those two?